# Concatenate numpy arrays over Python dicts

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a list of Python dicts. The elements in the dicts are numpy arrays. For example:

```
out = []
import numpy as np
d = dict()
d["test1"] = np.random.rand(10,64,80)
d["test2"] = np.random.rand(5,64,80)
out.append(d)

d = dict()
d["test1"] = np.random.rand(13,64,80)
d["test2"] = np.random.rand(29,64,80)
d["test3"] = np.random.rand(30,64,80)
out.append(d)

d = dict()
d["test1"] = np.random.rand(2,64,80)
d["test2"] = np.random.rand(27,64,80)
d["test3"] = np.random.rand(25,64,80)
out.append(d)
```

Now I would like to concatenate all numpy arrays having same keys in order of appearance in the list. That means the final dictionary should be as follows:

```
final = dict()
final["test1] = np.concatenate((out[0]["test1"], out[1]["test1"], out[2]["test1"]), axis=0)
final["test2] = np.concatenate((out[0]["test2"], out[1]["test2"], out[2]["test2"]), axis=0)
final["test3] = np.concatenate((out[1]["test3"], out[2]["test3"]), axis=0)
```

I don't know the number of elements in the list. How can I do this? Because the numpy arrays are pretty large, it would be nice to make it in a way to reduce amount of memory used.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve here. This looks a bit more like an attempt at a solution rather than a description of the problem. That's helpful, but random numbers aren't particularly good at illustrating a problem--can you just show the original numpy list of dicts, then show the expected output dict and the transformation you're trying to perform. Almost certainly, hardcoding the numbers can be improved upon. Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: Collecting arrays in a list or tuple does not increase their memory use. It's when you use `concatenate` that you get a new array with a big jump in memory use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop each dictionary of `out` list and concat all dictionaries where the field is filled with a numpy array. *e.g.*

```py
final = {
   k: np.concatenate([dct[k] for dct in out if dct.get(k)], axis=0)
   for k in ("test1", "test2", "test3",)
}
```